# Solidus: [Spree WARNING] Missing migrations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, e-commerce, spree, solidus

I have a problem with Solidus 2.10.2 where when I run `rails g spree:install` several migration errors come up. Starting with `[Spree WARNING] Missing migrations.` and ending with `[Spree WARNING] Run bundle exec rake railties:install:migrations` to get them. but when I run `bundle exec rake railties:install:migrations` nothing happens...

I tried deleting the database (rails db:drop) and all my custom migration files as well before running the spree generator again however I get the same results. I put the full error in a bitbucket snippet (https://bitbucket.org/goldenBoySailsLow/workspace/snippets/5LGqez) I would appreciate any help

system info: rails 5.2.4.4, ruby 2.7.2, ImageMagick 6.9.10-23 and sqlite3 3.31.1 running on ubuntu 20.04 lts

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue because I forgot to specify the version in the Gemfile. When I deployed, it started using solidus 2.11.2 instead of 2.10.2.
Specifying the version solved the problem for me.